# VueJS - Hide and Show based on form selection

Tags: vue.js, show-hide, v-for, v-model

I have a form select element and an array to display some device information on the page. I render all the devices with a v-for loop and I couldn't find a way to display them based on the selection from `form-select` element because I am not allowed to use `v-if` statements with `v-for`

Here is my form select;

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options" size="sm" class="mr-10px"></b-form-select>
```

And here is how I display the devices in HTML;

```
                    <tr v-for="device in devices" :key="device.id">
                        <td style="width: 20px;">
                            <img :src="device.image"alt="..." />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h6>{{device.name}}</h6></span>
                            <span>{{device.model}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span 
                                class="badge font-size-12" 
                                :class="{
                                    'bg-soft-danger': device.traffic >= '10' && device.traffic <= '30',
                                    'bg-soft-warning': device.traffic >= '30' && device.traffic <= '60',
                                    'bg-soft-success': device.traffic > '50',
                                }"
                            >
                                {{device.traffic}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="badge font-size-12" :class="[device.status == 'Active' ? 'bg-soft-success' : 'bg-soft-danger']">{{device.status}}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And now here is my javascript file for form-select options and device array...

```
export const devices = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: require("./mini.svg"),
        name: "Username 1",
        model: "Device Model",
        traffic: "10mb",
        status: "Active",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: require("./mini.svg"),
        name: "Username 2",
        model: "Device Model 2",
        traffic: "20mb",
        status: "Active",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: require("./mini.svg"),
        name: "Username 3",
        model: "Device Model 3",
        traffic: "30mb",
        status: "Deactive",
    },
];

export const options = [
    {
        id: 1,
        value: "All",
        text: "All",
        disabled: false,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        value: "Location",
        text: "Location",
        disabled: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        value: "Traffic",
        text: "Traffic",
        disabled: false,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        value: "Active",
        text: "Active",
        disabled: false,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        value: "Deactive",
        text: "Deactive",
        disabled: false,
    },
]
```

And here is how I import the javascript file and use these as data in my .vue file...

```
import { devices, options } from '../devices'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            devices: devices,
            options: options,
            selected: 'All',
        };
    },
};
```

Here is my question; how do I display these devices when the form-select is changed to `Active` or `Deactive`

I cant say `v-if something equals to 'Active'` because Vue doesn't let me use v-if with v-for. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `computed` property,

```
computed: {
  computedDevices() {
    // filter by conditions here
    return this.devices.filter(device => device.status === 'Active')
  }
}
```

then use `computedDevices` in the `v-for` instead of `devices`

```
<tr v-for="device in computedDevices" :key="device.id" >
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: It's working but how do I do that for all options in the form select? Active, deactive, location, traffic etc... In this way, only the active ones is showing even the form-select's v-model is equal to 'All' or something else. I want it to be dynamic and based on form-select's v-model value

Answer (score 0):

you can use v-if and v-for just don't do it in the same tag.
use v-if before or inside v-for

e.g.

```
<div v-for="i in 10">
   <div v-if="i>
     ...
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue does not support using `v-if` inline with `v-for`. You can create a parent `v-for` and child is `v-if`

Something like this

```
<template v-for="..." :key="...">
   <div|tr|anytag v-if="...">
   </div|tr|anytag>
</template>
```

Comment: When I do that, it says that template v-for cannot be keyed...

Comment: @YasinDemirkaya are you sure?